# Get session creation time in Grails + Apache Shiro

Tags: grails, httpsession

There's this text `Last seen:` field in my application that shows for how long the current user is logged on the system (e.g. 5 seconds ago, 4 hours ago, 3 days ago, etc.). Now for me to do this, I need to determine either:

- the time Apache Shiro performs the login; or
- the time the current Grails Session has been created.

Then subtract it to the current time. But how can I access the creation time of either of the two? Or are there any better ways to achieve this not using the mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller action you can write like this:

```
class MyController {

    // Considering this action is secured for logged in user only
    def foo() {
        long currentMillis = new Date().getTime()
        long sessionCreationMillis = session.getCreationTime()

        long loggedInFor = currentMillis - sessionCreationMillis
        println "User has been logged in for $loggedInFor miliseconds"
    }
}
```

Now, you got how long the user has been logged in (in milliseconds). Further, you can use the [TimeUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) library to convert your milliseconds to other values.

Or, you can also use any Javascript library like [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) if you are planning to do it on client side.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea about Apache Shiro but I can tell you how to get the `session creation time`.

It's pretty simple actually, there is a method called `getCreationTime()` in `HttpSession`. Here is the [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getCreationTime())

You can invoke this method on the `session attribute` available in controllers. This will return the time in milliseconds as `long`.